# Picture download from url via lotus script

Tags: url, download, lotus-notes, image, lotusscript

I want to download one picture from url to my Lotus Notes application.
I can get text field from url, but image is difficult.
I try to put pic to a rich text field, but it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download an image from URL via LotusScript with the help of a little Script Library of type "Java".

Create a Script Library "GetImageFromUrl" of Type "Java" and put in following code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class GetImageFromUrl {

    public static boolean getImageFromUrl(String imageUrl, String filePath) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the method `getImageFromUrl(imageUrl, filePath)` in your LotusScript code to download the image to a file. From there you can attach the image file to a RichText item with `rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", "c:/temp/image.jpg")`.

```
Option Declare

UseLSX "*javacon"  

Use "GetImageFromUrl"

Sub Initialize
    dim jSession As New JavaSession
    dim jClass As JavaClass
    Set jClass = jSession.GetClass( "GetImageFromUrl" )     
    If jClass.getImageFromUrl("https://your.url", "c:/temp/image.jpg") Then
        MessageBox "File is downloaded"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've noticed the filePath is given with forward slashes "/", is this necessary for Java, or is it acceptable to use the Windows convention with backslash "\"?