# File Download form url via lotus notes

Tags: excel, csv, url, download, lotus-notes

Referring to this post:
[Picture download from url via lotus script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484864/picture-download-from-url-via-lotus-script)

what i have to do change if i want to download a file (.csv or .xlsx) from an url ?

Comment: You already found the solution to your question. Never, I repeat NEVER use code, that you don't understand in your own projects. If you understood the java- code (and it is not that hard to understand even without any knowledge about java, just as a developer), then you would have seen, that this is already a solution for your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picture download from url via lotus script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484864/picture-download-from-url-via-lotus-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change nothing. The code behind the link works for all sorts of files. I just named the method "getImage...()" because the topic of original question was about downloading images.

Comment: i try to use your solution with a google spreadsheet download link but your solution doesn't work: the link is like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/export?format=csv